# Is their any way to do Frame by Frame Animation in canvas ..?

Tags: android, android-canvas

For normal Activity with the help of ImageView we are able to attain Frame Animation ("Through some online tutorial i done that")

```
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadimage);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
```

but here in Canvas i'm using Bitmap to get an image to the view, their i'm stuck..

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.loadimage);
```

is their any way to do frame animation in canvas..?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an animated custom view using `SurfaceView` with a `Thread` to schedule the animation times properly.

The idea is to extend from `SurfaceView`, get the `Canvas` from the `SurfaceHolder`, draw on it, post the draw on the screen, and repeat (done in a background thread). A basic example:

```
public class CustomView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread animationThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = this.getHolder();
    }

    // called from Activity's onResume() to start the thread
    public void resume() {          
        running = true;
        animationThread = new Thread(this);
        animationThread.start();         
    }

    // called from Activity's onPause() to end the thread
    public void pause() {        
        running = false;                        
        while(true) {
            try {
                animationThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }

    // run until pause() is called
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) { 
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            // your drawing logic goes here: 
            // - calculate the time of the frame
            // - draw a different bitmap each time ...            
            canvas.drawBitmap(...)     
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }  
}
```

To handle the size of the view, you would need to override onMeasure() and onSizeChanged().

For a better understanding of how this works:

- http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/06/android-graphics-and-animation-part-i/
- http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/android-graphics-and-animation-part-ii-animation/
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: K i'll give a try . Thanks for the response.